# How to get height of Dialog in Material UI using ref?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI for my React project, and I'm in a situation where I want to get the height of a Dialog. So, I tried to do something like this:

```
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';

class MyDialog extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.dialogRef = React.createRef();
   }

   render() {
      if (this.dialogRef.curent) {
         console.log(this.dialogRef.current);
      }

      return (
         <Dialog maxWidth='sm'
                 innerRef={this.dialogRef}
         >
            // Rest removed for brevity
         </Dialog>
      );
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(withLocalize(MyDialog)));
```

Now with the code above, I see an object printed with the `console.log(this.dialogRef)` line, and it has a property called `refs`, which is an empty object. How can I get the height of the `Dialog` in this case? Either inside the `MyDialog` component, or assuming I have another component called `Main` which calls `MyDialog` inside its render method?

Please note that I'm using `"react": "^16.6.3"` and `"@material-ui/core": "^3.6.1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe RootRef in this case will find the wrong DOM element. I think you want the div from the Paper component inside the Dialog to get the height. You can do this by overriding the component for the Paper:

```
const PaperComponent = ({ dialogRef, ...other }) => {
  return <div ref={dialogRef} {...other} />;
};
```

```
     <Dialog
        PaperProps={{ component: PaperComponent, dialogRef: this.dialogRef }}
      >
```

Here's a modified version of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vxz5lq1jr

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this seems much closer to what I wanna achieve. I see you use `useEffect` for logging the offsetHeight. Can I somehow store the height inside the variable, so I can access it also from the class that renders the Dialog? Because, if I try to console log the offset value inside the class, it gives null when the Dialog opens and the actual value when it is closing.

Comment: @terett I think it is a matter of timing. There is a transition applied to the opening of the dialog, so you need a delay of some sort before the height will be available.

Comment: @terett You could have the Paper component place the height in context in the effect in order to communicate it to something higher up in the hierarchy.

Comment: Actually I do not even need to pass it to something higher. I also pass `style` for the `PaperProps`. The thing is that I want to modify the style depending on the height of the Dialog. So, a short delay might work I guess. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of style change are you trying to do? You should be able to do the style change within a `useLayoutEffect` in PaperComponent, but you also may be able to handle this without a ref at all by using a media query within styles: https://codesandbox.io/s/w4y5qnm87

Comment: Depending on the height of it, I make a small calculation, and depending on the result of the calculation I set either the top or bottom CSS style.

Comment: Here's an example using useLayoutEffect for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/942ym6k964. Since you don't need the ref elsewhere, it means this could be further simplified to use `useRef` directly in PaperComponent rather than passing the ref in as a prop.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly! Wish I could have upvoted more :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ref` prop directly since Material-UI v4.0.0-alpha.3.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const myRef = React.useRef();

  return <Dialog ref={myRef} />;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0r6vj63l3

Comment: I see, thanks. So, there is no way to do this in earlier version of Material UI and by relying on withStyles?

Comment: You can use the `RootRef` component with Material-UI v3.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work if I surround `<Dialog>` inside `<RootRef>`, but I cannot get the height. It always shows 0. I tried `offsetHeight`, `clientHeight,` even `getBoundingClientRect()`. All values are 0. Also, in first opening of the dialog, the ref is null. I need to close and re-open the dialog to get the actual DOM element. But, as I said even then values are 0.

Comment: @OlivierTassinari My answer shows a way that works for v3, but please chime in if you think there is a better way.

Comment: @terett I think even for v4, the dialog ref won't provide the DOM element you want since it gets the `div` for the Modal component which seems to have the full browser window height rather than the height of the dialog content.

Comment: @RyanCogswell For v4, it seems to work fine, but not for v3.

Comment: When I try the v4 example I get a height, but it changes when I change the browser window size even if the content size is unaffected.